# Mkusb Error "no suitable target device found"

Tags: boot, 17.10, live-usb, mkusb

When I run Mkusb, I get this error. I checked the ISO file.
The ISO file I run is Ubuntu 64 bit 17.10.1 desktop.
(I get this error after I select the ISO file) -Google Translate

[image]

**Updating:** I'm writing output about the error here -Google translate

```
sudo lsblk -f
NAME           FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sr0                                                              
sda                                                              
├─sda2         ext4         bea9d037-224f-48c8-82c4-a18e97ec8d2e /
├─sda3         swap         2e0d5641-9b89-40c4-8669-0e056abed5b4 
│ └─cryptswap1 swap         bdf98fac-5ddb-40b8-a7a0-ed9a6a13e924 [SWAP]
└─sda1         vfat         59A2-C6F5                            /boot/efi

sudo lsblk -m

NAME            SIZE OWNER GROUP MODE
sr0            1024M root  cdrom brw-rw----
sda              10G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda2          7,5G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda3            2G root  disk  brw-rw----
│ └─cryptswap1    2G root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sda1          512M root  disk  brw-rw----

sudo parted -ls

Model: ATA VBOX HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 10,7GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32           EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   8591MB  8053MB  ext4
 3      8591MB  10,7GB  2145MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: WDC WD32 00BPVT-22ZEST0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  320GB  320GB  primary  ntfs


Model: Linux device-mapper (crypt) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: 2145MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Flags
 1      0,00B  2145MB  2145MB  linux-swap(v1)

df

Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                    478016         0    478016   0% /dev
tmpfs                   100876      3664     97212   4% /run
/dev/sda2              7609816   6797192    403024  95% /
tmpfs                   504368       220    504148   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                   504368         0    504368   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1               523248      3500    519748   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                   100876        44    100832   1% /run/user/1000
/home/burak/.Private   7609816   6797192    403024  95% /home/burak
/dev/sdb1            312568828 305643148   6925680  98% /media/burak/BURAK DİSK2000
```

Comment: Tell us a little about the USB that you have inserted in the computer...

Comment: I have not chosen USB yet. After selecting the ISO file it gives this error. - Translate

Comment: Please post the output of the following commands: `sudo lsblk -f` ; `sudo lsblk -m` ; `sudo parted -ls` ; `df` Please edit your original question to show the output of the commands and indent each line 4 spaces to render it as 'code'. This will help us help you :-)

Comment: It is possible, that there is no available candidate target device. You need a third device for example `/dev/sdc` or `/dev/mmcblk0` because `/dev/sda`is the live drive (booted from) and `/dev/sdb` contains the source file (the iso file). If you wish to use `/dev/sdb` as target device, you must select the source file (the iso file) from another drive, for example `/dev/sda`.

Comment: I notice a problem with `lsblk`: While `parted` and `df` show both `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`, `lsblk` shows only `/dev/sda` (unless you truncated the output). Mkusb relies on `lsblk`. On the other hand, the output in your screenshot indicates, that mkusb really can see `/dev/sdb`. I suggest that you connect a third device, for example a USB pendrive or memory card, and try again. Chances are that  `lsblk` and mkusb will recognize it and let you use it as target device.

Comment: I used a third device as you said and it worked thanks ! But its shows me 4 gb s of free space to use even ı set it to 5 is there any way to improve this?

Comment: Please 1. Tell me how you set it to 5 GB free space and 2. Show the output of `sudo lsblk -m` when the USB boot drive (that you made) is inserted.

Comment: I did the settings like this -Translate  https://imgur.com/89oG7hg (I showed these settings using a different system VirtualBox-Ubuntu64bit)

Answer (score 0):

- I suggested that you should connect a third device, for example a USB pendrive or memory card, and try again. You connected a USB pendrive, and `lsblk` and `mkusb` recognized it and let you use it as target device.
- The next step is to get 5 GB for persistence.

  - According to the screenshot you uploaded,

    [image]

    The available drive space is shared between the `casper-rw` partition `/dev/sdb5`, 4 GB, and the `usbdata` partition `/dev/sdb1`, 1.6 GB. I did the following calculation with `bc`,

    ```
    $ bc
    bc 1.06.95
    Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
    For details type `warranty'. 
    100*5/(1.6+4)
    89
    ```

    and suggest that you select 89 %  or maybe rounded to 90 % for persistence. You can also select 100% (of the remaining drive space) for persistence, if you think that a very small `usbdata` partition is not useful.
  - It is also possible to use `gparted` and shrink the `usbdata` partition and after that 'grow' the `casper-rw` partition (to use the unallocated space).